What should a Buddhist do, if he is required by the law to join the army and fight?
What should a Buddhist do, if he is required by the law to join the army and fight in war?
Related question 
As I read the answers to the above related question, this very real question was raised.
What should someone do?

flee the country?
join the army?
hide and avoid being captured?


The thing to watch for here is reactivity due to fear. A government has power and can punish disobedience; if you fear that power, that fear can lead you to make unwise choices. The simplest thing to do is to go to whatever government department handles conscription and tell them that you're buddhist and unwilling to do harm. They may grant you an exemption; they may induct you into a non-combat unit (medical or support); they may say they don't care and that you're required to serve. If it's the last case, calmly remind them (and yourself) that while they can issue you a weapon, they can't make you use it, and that you don't want to put other soldiers at risk through your unwillingness to do harm.
If the government is intractable it might want to send you to jail. Then you'll need to consider whether you want to leave your nation and friends and family (your current life) behind to settle elsewhere, or to accept the jail term for what it is. It's an honest choice. And if you choose not to abandon your life, remember that jail is not that different from monastic orders: it can an opportunity to deepen your practice.

Unfortunately, a jail term can have severe consequences on subsequent employment prospects and other aspects of life such as disqualification or suspension from certain social benefits.

@Desmon: Yes, I know; that's one of the fears that a government tries to leverage to compel obedience. But we have to come to terms with it. Ask yourself: are you willing to agree to do harm now so that you can preserve the idea of future comfort and success? That comfort/success is an illusion: not something you currently have, just something you want to get. To be punished, you must accept that what happens to you is punishment (that things could have been better if you hadn't done wrong). If you follow the dharma, then nothing that happens to you is a punishment; it's just what is.

Sigh, +1 for making a stand. It is what it is.

Apparently it's historical fact that e.g. in World War 2, a majority of (non-Buddhist) front-line infantrymen (conscripts) fired their weapons, but not at each other.
